# JavaScript Library not working on server but it's working on local server

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm working on Laravel project and I'm using :

> cookieinfo.min.js

I'm facing a problem that the Cookies message is displayed on the local server but not working the online server

```
<script id="cookieinfo" src="/assets/frontend/js/cookieinfo.min.js"></script>
```

and I'm getting that message in the console

```
GET https://example.com/assets/frontend/js/cookieinfo.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

but all the other scripts are working fine on the live server

can anyone give me any advice or a fix to that bug

Comment: Do "all the other scripts" have the same `src`? `src="/assets/frontend/js/cookieinfo.mil.js"`

Comment: @bananabrann yes, they are all the same form as I'll show you in example
`<script src="/assets/frontend/js/typed-custom.js"></script>`

`<script src="/assets/frontend/js/particles.js"></script>`

`<script src="/assets/frontend/js/app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Proper Url

```
{{url('/assets/frontend/js/cookieinfo.min.js')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When cut `.htaccess` and `index.php` files must give public folder as path.

Try with this

```
<script  id="cookieinfo" src="{{URL::asset('public/js/cookieinfo.min.js')}}"></script>
```

OR

```
<script  id="cookieinfo" src="{{URL::asset('frontend/js/cookieinfo.min.js')}}"></script>
```

**UPDATE :**

Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered somewhere else in another view or layout. This can be particularly useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child views

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/assets/frontend/js/cookieinfo.min.js"></script>
@endpush
```

See more https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#stacks

Comment: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/js/cookieinfo.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` that what I get when using that method